# listener for h3 tags do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pomodoro clock and I'm having problems with listeners for minBreak and plusBreak respectively. the plusWork minWork jquery listener work just fine, but for some reason the listeners for minBreak and plusBreak do not work. Could someone tell me why? here's the code (don't mind the design too much.. is not finished)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //variables
  var workTime = 2; //working time
  var breakTime = 10; //break time
  var seconds = 00;
  var minutes = workTime; //setting clock = to workTime
  var clockDisplay = document.getElementById("display");
  var counterId = 0;
  var state = "on";

  //start clock whenc button clicked
  $("#start").click(function() {
    console.log("started!");
    setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    $(this).hide(); //hide start button
    $("#stop").show(); //show stop button
  });

  //stop clock when stop clicked
  $("#stop").click(function() {
    console.log("stopped!");
    state = "off";
    minutes = workTime;
    seconds = 0;
    clockDisplay.innerHTML = workTime + ":00";
    $(this).hide(); //hiding stop
    $("#start").show(); //showing start
  });

  //add work time
  $('.plusWork').click(function() {
    workTime++;
    $('.work').text(workTime);
    console.log(workTime);
  });

  //substract work time
  $('.minWork').click(function() {
    workTime--;
    $('.work').text(workTime);
    console.log(workTime);
  });

  //add break time
  $('.plusBreak').click(function() {
    breakTime++;
    $('.break').text(breakTime);
    console.log(breakTime);
  });

  //substract break time
  $('.minBreak').click(function() {
    breakTime--;
    $('.break').text(breakTime);
    console.log(breakTime);
  });

  //countdown function
  function countDown() {
    //if workTime = 0 reset counter and stop
    if (minutes == 0 || state == 'off') {
      clearTimeout(counterId);
      return;
    }
    //when seconds < 0 substract a minute
    else if (seconds < 0) {
      minutes--;
      seconds = 59;
      clockDisplay.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else {
      //if second single digit add 0
      if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
      clockDisplay.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
      seconds--;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #22313f;
  ;
}

.title {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.clockContainer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#display {}


/* .timer {
      margin: 0 50px;
      margin-top: 70px;
      text-align: center;
      border: solid black 1px;
      font-size: 44px;
      width: 500px;
      height: 200px;
      display: inline-block;
      
    } */

.controlContainer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.control {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.time {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.minus {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.plus {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- header title -->
  <div class="title primary-text">
    <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- clock container -->
  <div class="clockContainer">
    <h2>Session</h2>
    <!-- timer / clock -->
    <div class="timer">
      <h1 id="display">30:00</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- this section for controlling clock -->
    <div class="controlContainer">
      <div class="control">
        <div id="start" class="button title">Start</div>
        <div id="stop" class="button hide title">Stop</div>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <h3 class="time work">30</h3>
        <h3 class="title">Work</h3>
        <h3 class="minWork ticker minus">-</h3>
        <h3 class="plusWork ticker plus">+</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <h3 class="time break">10</h3>
        <h3 class="title">Break</h3>
        <h3 class="minBrake ticker minus">-</h3>
        <h3 class="plusBrake ticker plus">+</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what you want is `.mouseup()` or `.mousedown()` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: Spelling matters you have `.minBreak` in jquery and `.minBrake` in html

Comment: Just checked what @JoeB. suggested and he is right! Its works when you change  `minBrake` and `plusBrake` in JS

Comment: it actually work!

Comment: @miatech Can you tell me why you accepted the answer when its clearly copy pasted from JoeB's comment? You should  not accept the answer from Jared or at least thank Joe for finding the mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo in h3 `class`:

```
<h3 class="minBrake ticker minus">-</h3>
<h3 class="plusBrake ticker plus">+</h3>
```

Should be:

```
<h3 class="minBreak ticker minus">-</h3>
<h3 class="plusBreak ticker plus">+</h3>
```